# Typo in tag in developer story

Tags: feature-request, tags, developer-story

I've just started to test developer story and added one project.

In the technologies field I've made a typo - `Adnroid` instead of `Android`. And `Adnroid` is showed as a tag on SO. If I click it, it shows

> 0 questions tagged

For me it looks like that tag was created. Am I right?
If no, maybe you don't need to highlight technologies as tags, if they don't have such one?

Answer (score 10):

> For me it looks like that tag was created. Am I right?

No. Don't worry, the tag wasn't created.

> maybe you don't need to highlight technologies as tags, if they don't have such one?

I agree. IMO it's not useful for anyone to be linked to unexisting tag (especially if it's a typo). If you want to demonstrate knowledge on a technology that *doesn't* have a tag, you can add it in the description section.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate knowledge on a technology that doesn't have a tag, you can also ask and self-answer the tag's first question!

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom If the tag exists.. definitely.